# How do I get a colormap from JPEG file in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, 3d

I have a jpg image file of the surface of Neptune. My intention is to build a texture mapping (see [Matlab help about this topic](http://www.mathworks.es/help/techdoc/visualize/f0-18164.html#f0-9250)). I have used the command imread with the file but jpg files have not a colormap (in general, the command imread produces an MxNx3 matrix and a colormap is a Mx3 matrix). I would like to know how I could do it.

Like an image is more valuable than 1000 words (sometimes), my purpose is doing something like that [example](http://www.mathworks.es/products/matlab/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/matlab/earthmap.html) but for Neptune.

Comment: Note: A picture may be worth 0 words: http://spikedmath.com/168.html

Comment: @Jonas: ha, ha, very good observation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MxNx3 array is a RGB array, i.e. at position (x,y), the third dimension corresponds to a triplet of red, green, and blue values.

To change from an RGB image to a indexed image with a colormap, you use the function [RGB2IND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rgb2ind.html)

```
[indexedImage,colorMap] = rgb2ind(rgbImage, nColors); %# set nColors to e.g. 128
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, which was allowed me along with Matlab's help about texture mapping resolve my problem.

Comment: @Jonas if the image is already indexed, can you please tell me How I can get the color map?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan: If all you have is the indexed image, there is no way to know what the colormap was, since all the indexed image contains are the indices into a separate array that defines the colors.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for my question based on the answer of Jonas:

```
[X, map] = rgb2ind(imread('neptune.jpg'),128);
[x,y,z] = sphere(50);
x = 24764*x;
y = 24764*y;
z = 24764*z;
props.FaceColor= 'texture';
props.EdgeColor = 'none';
props.Cdata = flipud(X); % it is necessary to do this for getting the 
% appropiate image on the sphere
surface(x,y,z,props);
colormap(map);
axis equal;
view([71 14]);
```